# Compiling issue with Boost asio

Tags: boost, sdk, boost-asio, yocto

My goal is to **cross-compile** a code file with **Yocto SDK** on my host machine to make it executable on my target Board. I am using **SUMO** Yocto version and **GCC 7.3 cross compiler**.

First of all, to get with YOCTO cross compiling I created a file Hello.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf ("Hello World!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled the file executing :
`make hello`

Now I have a compiled file which is ready to be executed on my target board.

But now I have multiple .h files and multiple .cpp files and a main file.
When I execute main file like this :
`make main`
an error occurs:

> main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory
>   include  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
>   : recipe for target 'main' failed make: *** [main] Error 1

I think that I have a problem with **Boost** and **asio.hpp**.
Is the boost library included in my Yocto Linux image ?
What is the problem with asio.hpp ?
How can I fix this please ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your Makefile? Have you checked if that header file is indeed in your SDK rootfs?

Comment: You'll probably need to add something like `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "boost-dev"`

Comment: I add the variable `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "boost-dev"` to local.conf file ?

Comment: Yes, local.conf is ok

Comment: I added `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "boost-dev"` and `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"` to local.conf . There is no error now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that, actually, you're not using the SDK but the toolchain which only includes glibc along with some basic tools and gdb; usually used to build test apps and debug. So that, you need to build the real SDK which contains, in addition to the toolchain, the dev version (libs/headers/other files) of the packages installed in the rootfs of your image. This can be accomplished by:

```
bitbake -c populate_sdk <your_image>
```

Once the SDK is built you need to install it through the generated installer script. Also, don't forget to source the environment setup script before you start to work!

For further information refer to https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-building-an-sdk-installer

Comment: When i wanted to build SDK, I executed this : `Bitbake meta-toolchain` and then a directory named SDK appeared under tmp/deploy/ which contains .sh file that i must source when i want to use the cross compiler. Is that not the real SDK that i must use ?

Comment: What you're building is just the toolchain (`bitbake meta-toolchain`); buildtools (such as cross-compiler, make, ar, ld...) and the glibc (GNU C standard library), like a trimmed version of the SDK. As you can see, with these tools you can build simple apps, but as long as you need to build an app that depends on third-party libraries/headers/whatever you need the complete SDK (`bitbake -c populate_sdk <your_image>`), which contains the dev packages of the packages that you have installed in  your image rootfs (i.e. you should have installed bison on your image).

Comment: I executed `bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-minimal` I checked SDK directory under tmp/deploy directory, there is a new .sh file created. I installed SDK through the script, i sourced the environment. I executed `make main` and some error appears

Comment: Which kind of error? Please, edit your question with the error log. Have you added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"` to your `local.conf` before building the SDK?

Comment: NO I did not add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "boost"` to my local.conf. I will add it and try again. But should I re-build all my Linux image + SDK or just re-build SDK after modification ?

Comment: I guess that rebuilding the SDK would be enough.

Comment: I re-build the Linux image and SDK after making modifications to local.conf file. The error is solved now, thank you.